# Evaluate a integer expression in bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I have a set of piped commands that generates an integer expression. A sample looks like `(1 +(0x1f+0x02))`
I can evaluate this expression (get the resulting value), by enclosing it in `$()`, so:

```
$ echo $((1 +(0x1f+0x02)))
34
```

I'm interested in getting this to work in a single command, so I tried enclosing my entire series of piped commands within `$()`, but it seems like bash wasn't able to evaluate the expression. This snippet probably replicates the problem I am seeing:

```
$ TEST="(1 +(0x1f+0x02))"

$ echo "$TEST"
(1 +(0x1f+0x02))

$ echo $($TEST)
bash: (1: command not found
```

Not sure what I'm missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic expansion happens within `$((...))`, while `$(...)` is a command substitution.  Since there is no command called `(1`, which is the first word of your `TEST` variable's value, you get an error from the shell when it tries to use `$TEST` as a command in a command substitution.

You may have wanted to do

```bash
expression='(1 +(0x1f+0x02))'

echo "$(( "$expression" ))"
```

With versions of `bash` older than release 4.4, drop the inner set of double quotes.  Release 4.4 was the first release of `bash` that allowed for the expansion of double-quoted identifiers within an arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting errors with that though,

bash: "(1 +(0x1f+0x02))" : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""(1 +(0x1f+0x02))" ")

Comment: @rookie I can't provoke that error myself. What version of the `bash` shell are you using on what system?

Comment: 4.3.48 on ubuntu 16

Comment: @rookie Ubuntu 16 reached end-of-life in April 2021. You should consider upgrading. Not for the sake of this issue, but for the sake of keeping the security of your system up to date.

Comment: @rookie Also, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem to work!